# Python if a = this or this or this

Tags: python

If I have a function:

```
if a_string == "a" or a_string == "b" or a_string == "c":
    # do this
```

how can I write that differently without the repetitive or statements? Or is that the best way?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, i just wrote this really quick

Comment: I rolled back your question because you've changed it to a different one, invalidating the answers, and the new one doesn't make much sense: no string can be equal to "a" and also equal to "b" and also equal to "c".

Comment: @Brian: Perhaps you should consider putting a little more effort in your questions then? We try to put time and thought into our answers, too!

Comment: Oops, thanks.. should have thought that through.

Answer (score 9):

```
if a_string in ["a", "b", "c"]:
    # do stuff
```

Make sure you use `==` in your conditions, not `=`, or else Python will throw an error

EDIT: As Nigel Tufnel points out in his answer, you can also check for membership in a `set`, e.g. `{'a', 'b', 'c'}`. I believe this is actually faster in general, though it really won't matter practically if you only have three things in the list/set.

Answer (score 5):

You can test for a list membership:

```
if a_string in ["a", "b", "c"]:
    # do your thing
```

or you can test for a set membership:

```
if a_string in {"a", "b", "c"}:
    # do your thing
```

or you can test for a tuple membership:

```
if a_string in ("a", "b", "c"):
    # do your thing
```

I think that the `list` way is the most pythonic way, the `set` way is the most right way, the `tuple` way is the most bizzare way.

EDIT: as DSM and iCodez have pointed out I was wrong: the `tuple` way is the fastest (probably not, see EDIT#2) and the most pythonic way. Live and learn!

EDIT#2: I know that microbenchmarking is the most evil thing since Adolf Hitler but I'm posting it anyway:

```
python -O -m timeit '"c" in ("a", "b", "c")'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0709 usec per loop

python -O -m timeit '"c" in ["a", "b", "c"]'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0703 usec per loop

python -O -m timeit '"c" in {"a", "b", "c"}'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.184 usec per loop
```

I won't interpret the `timeit` results but the `set` timing is rather peculiar (probably it's because of the, er, I won't interpret the results).

Comment: Why do you call the tuple way bizarre?  By my rough count, it's 3-4 times as common as either of the others in the Python 2.7.4 source itself.

Comment: Also, in this case, the tuple would be the fastest solution. ;)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is the tuple the fastest solution? I've always heard that membership testing in a set (and a frozenset) is significantly faster than in a list, which seems to makes sense since lookup times can be faster than O(n). Is it just because the set/tuple involved here is very small?

Comment: @gms7777 - Yes, that is exactly it.  As this [link](http://technobeans.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/performance-for-testing-memberships-list-vs-tuples-vs-sets/) will demonstrate, it all comes down to the size of the collection.  Using a tuple or a list is a lot more efficient when dealing with *small collections*.  However, a set is *much* faster with larger ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if a_string in ["a", "b", "c"]:
    do this
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if a_string in ("a", "b", "c"):
    # do this
```

And you have an error in your example. Assignment "=" is not allowed in the "if" statement. You should use "==".

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous, in the specific case of checking for a single character in a string, you can do this:

```
if a_string in "abc":
```

Another similar idiom that you are likely to find useful is this:

Instead of:

```
if a_string == "abcdefg" or b_string == "abcdefg" or c_string == "abcdefg":
```

You can do this:

```
if any(i == "abcdefg" for i in (a_string, b_string, c_string)):
```